# LaTeX Tree Diagram

Tags: nodes, graphs, tikz-node, node-connections

I'm trying to recreate the diagram on this website: http://www.njohnston.ca/2013/04/the-minimal-superpermutation-problem/
and am finding difficulty with joining all the nodes in the third row to a singular node. This is what I have got so far:

```
\begin{center} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=5em,
  every node/.style = {shape=circle,
    draw, align=center,}]]
  \node {$123121321$}
    child { node {123} 
        child {node {1234123} } }
    child { node {231}
            child {node {2314231} } }
    child {node {312} 
        child {node {3124312} } }
    child {node {213} 
        child {node {2134213} } }
    child {node {132}
        child {node {1324132} } }
    child {node {321}
        child {node {3214321} } }; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se.  Please don't post code fragments, but instead put your fragment into a complete compilable document.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `forest`. The `\foreach` loop at the end can be used for your original code, too (after changing the node names).

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

    \begin{forest}
for tree={draw, ellipse,edge={-latex}}
[123121,alias=top
    [123
        [1234123,alias=n-1]
    ]
    [231
        [2314231,alias=n-2]
    ]
    [312
        [3124312,alias=n-3]
    ]
    [213
        [2134213,alias=n-4]
    ]
    [132
        [1324132,alias=n-5]
    ]
    [321
        [3214321,alias=n-6]
    ]
]
\node[ellipse,draw] (Pft) at ([yshift=-pi*1.1cm]top) {1234\dots};
\foreach \X in {1,...,6}
{\draw[-latex] (n-\X) -- (Pft);}
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]